# How to get more than one random different item in this javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, getjson, floor

I have **[this code](http://painfulmouth.com/index2.php)** that picks up a random text link using getJSON. It picks up one random item at a time. I'd like to know how to pick up more than one different item and show them in `#randomkeyword`. All I can come up with is setting up the script two times, but I think it may have a chance of picking up the same item,  Is there any way to do that?

```
jQuery.getJSON('random.json', function(data) { //Ajax call

var item = data.link[Math.floor(Math.random()*data.link.length)]; 

jQuery('<a title="' + item.des + '" href="http://' + item.url + '">'+ item.title +'</a>').appendTo

('#randomkeyword');

});
```

JSON File:

```
{"link":[{"title":"XXXX","url":"google.com","des":"light"},{"title":"CCCCCCC","url":"yahoo.com","des":"dark"},{"title":"DDDDDDDD","url":"song.com","des":"light"},{"title":"CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","url":"googlemap.com","des":"normal"},{"title":"RRRRRRRRRRRRRRR","url":"fun.com","des":"halo"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplicates, you can "shuffle" the list then just loop through it from the beginning.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the second item is the same as the first item. If so, you can select an other random item.

```
jQuery.getJSON('random.json', function(data) { //Ajax call

var item = data.link[Math.floor(Math.random()*data.link.length)];
var item2=item;//set second item same as first item to access the while loop

while(item==item2){
   item2 = data.link[Math.floor(Math.random()*data.link.length)];
}

jQuery('<a title="' + item.des + '" href="http://' + item.url + '">'+ item.title +'</a>').appendTo

('#randomkeyword');

});
//do the same for item2
```

Comment: I tried your script but it doesn't seem to work. Only one item is selected.

Comment: Did you do the `jQuery('<a title="' + item2.des + '" href="http://' + item2.url + '">'+ item2.title +'</a>').appendTo('#randomkeyword');`
bit?

Comment: yes, did you do that? That was what I meant by "//do the same for item2"

Answer (score 0):

So, I think you can store the list, then just iterate over it however many times you want, `splice` out the selected ones as you go (to avoid duplicates), and then run your jQuery on each element in the result array.  Note that this *does* modify the returned array, so make a copy of it first if you need that intact.

For example:

```
var data = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var numOfLinks = 2;
var result = [];
for(i = 0; i < numOfLinks; i++) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*data.length);
    var link = data[index];
    data.splice(index,1);
    result.push(link);
}
// iterate over result, doing your jQuery function over each element
```